# Avoiding different plot sizes depending on if ticklabels at end of colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, autoscaling, colorbar

I'm making some plots with matplotlib in Python, each of which have colorbars. Depending on the data, some colorbars will automatically have ticks/ticklabels the ends of the colorbars, and some won't. If there are ticklabels on the ends, the figure will rescale to accommodate the numbers poking off the ends. Consequently, such plots end up different sizes to those where ticklabels are not going past the ends of the colorbar. Similarly with subplots, the space between the subplots depends on where the ticks are on the colorbars. Is there a way to avoid this rescaling and just make sure to have the same axes size irrespective of the colorbar tick positions?

Comment: The axes size will only change if you instruct matplotlib to change it. Since we don't know your code, we don't know what you're doing for it to change.

Comment: don;'t use tight_layout, constrained_layout or bbox_inches=tight, all of which move things around automatically.  If you want to use one of those tools to get things close to right the first time, and then turn them off for subsequent plots, that is possible.  Read the relevant documentation for those functions, if that is what you are using.